# Retrofit - having custom logic run when the call is executed

Tags: java, spring-boot, retrofit, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for doing HTTP calls in a Spring boot application.

I'm trying to find a way to have my custom code runs whenever the API call is executed.

In the context of my custom code i need to know which method has invoked this API call.

I can think of three solutions but i have an issue with each one.

Let's use the following example code, let's say i have

```java
public interface MyClient {
  @GET("myurl")
  Call<MyDto> getInfo();
}
```

```java
@Bean
public MyClient getMyClient() {
  Retrofit myRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
      .client(oauthOkHttpClient())
      .addConverterFactory(jacksonConverterFactory)
      .build();
  return myRetrofit.create(MyClient.class);
}
```

```java
Call<MyDto> apiCall = myClient.getInfo();
apiCall.clone().execute()
```

I want my code to run once execute is called.

The three solutions:

#### 1. Use @Aspect

This has the potential of giving me access to the invoking method and run custom logic.

The thing is that while the interface is a Spring component, the code doing the execution of the call isn't.

Is there still a way of making something like this work?

```java
@Aspect
@Order(3)
@GlobalComponent
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("execution(* retrofit2.Call.execute())(..))")
  public void runLogic(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    do(...)
  }
}
```

#### 2. Implement okhttp3 Interceptor.

Since myRetrofit is using oauthOkHttpClient (see builder), the interceptor will be activated when a call is made.

The issue here is that all i have inside the interceptor is the okhttp3 Response, and i see no way of figuring out who was the invoking method and class (MyClient.getInfo)

#### 3. Provide a call back

```java
apiCall.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<MyDto> call, Response<MyDto> response) {}

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<MyDto> call, Throwable t) {}
});
```

The issue with is option is similar to the second option. Can't see a way to get the invoker.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can help you with option 1. But I am an AOP expert, not a general Spring expert and I know nothing about Retrofit and okhttp3. So please, condense your problem into a small, but complete project ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) reproducing the problem, publish it on GitHub and notify me in a comment. then I can take a look. BTW, are you aware of the fact that Spring AOP only works for Spring-managed components? Otherwise, you would need native AspectJ.

Comment: I wonder why you asked a question with a lot of text here, but then ignore the people who are offering to help you. Is that not a waste of time and effort on your own part? If you solved your problem already,please either write a comprehensive answer in order to help the community here, if anyone experiences the same problem in the future, or delete the question altogether.

Comment: @kriegaex  no disrespect intended. Your intuition was correct, i was checking a solution that might work. Now that i confirmed it to work i posted an answer below. Thanks for your comments and your offer to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way do it.

You need to create your own CallAdapter.Factory and pass it to the Retrofit builder when creating the client.

Here is an example:

```
Retrofit accountsRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(new MyAdapterFactory())
    .build();
```

The custom factory:

```
    public class MyAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(@NotNull Type returnType, @NotNull Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    CallAdapter<?, ?> nextCallAdapter = retrofit.nextCallAdapter(this, returnType, annotations);
    return new MonitorCallAdapter<>(nextCallAdapter);
  }

  private static final class MonitorCallAdapter<R, T> implements CallAdapter<R, T> {
    private final CallAdapter<?, ?> nextCallAdapter;

    private MonitorCallAdapter(CallAdapter<?, ?> nextCallAdapter) {
      this.nextCallAdapter = nextCallAdapter;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Type responseType() {
      return nextCallAdapter.responseType();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public T adapt(@NotNull Call<R> call) {
      return (T) nextCallAdapter.adapt(new MonitoredCall(call));
    }
  }

  private static final class MonitoredCall<T> implements Call<T> {
    private final Call<T> wrappedCall;

    private MonitoredCall(Call<T> call) {
      this.wrappedCall = call;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response<T> execute() throws IOException { 
      ////PUT_CUSTOM_LOGIC_HERE
      return wrappedCall.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(@NotNull Callback<T> callback) {
      wrappedCall.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<T> call, @NotNull Response<T> response) {
          callback.onResponse(call, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<T> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
          callback.onFailure(call, t);
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExecuted() {
      return wrappedCall.isExecuted();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
      wrappedCall.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCanceled() {
      return wrappedCall.isCanceled();
    }

    @Override
    public Call<T> clone() {
      return new MonitoredCall<T>(wrappedCall.clone());
    }

    @Override
    public Request request() {
      return wrappedCall.request();
    }
  }
}
```